# Three screw problem

Tags: problem-solving

There are three identical screws with diffrent amounts of nuts and disks on them.

Here is the problem picture:

[image: problem picture]

How do you calculate the weight of a screw, the nuts and the disks?

Comment: Form a system of 3 equations with the 3 unknowns...  & then solve it.

Comment: The weight of a screw, a nut and a disk are (s,n,d) . Now solve

$$ s + 3 d + n = 55, s +   d + 2 n = 42, s +   2 d + 3 n = 56. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the three images, we can say

\begin{cases}
1B+3D+1H &=55\\
1B+1D+2H &=42\\
1B+2D+3H &=56
\end{cases}

Where $B$ stands for the weight of bold, $D$ the disk's and $H$ the hexagon piece. Solving the system, we have
\begin{cases}
B &=23,\\
D &=9,\\
H &=5.
\end{cases}

Comment: It is unclear how you get the final answer.

Comment: @WilliamJohansson One way would be Gauss Elimination.

Comment: @GoodDeeds What is gauss elimination?

Comment: Look up "how to solve a system of linear equations".

Comment: Basically, in this problem the biggest step is the "intuition" behind the transformation of the image into the linear system. After this point there are may ways the answer could have been obtained. As @MrYouMath said, look for "how to solve a system of linear equations".